# Where are the Views located?

Tags: views, 8

This is related to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273701/wsod-on-views-list-page?noredirect=1#comment337618_273701) I asked.

Bottom line is that for some reason some junk view is stuck under the Views list and when accessing the List I get a WSOD.

I confirmed that is a view issue after uninstalling and reinstalling Views the problem went away.

An easier fix might be to take a look on the saved Views. But the major question here is where are the created Views located? (in a folder? in the DB?).

I just want to see that malformed View and delete it.

EDIT: A screenshot of the output of drush vl. Note the enabled view on the top that has no name or machine name.

[image]

Comment: Active View configuration is stored in the database. If a module is installing a default view via having configuration in its install directory, you might be stuck without also deleting that file. Do you have a contrib module that might be adding a View?

Answer (score 2):

Active views are stored in the config table of the db. For example the view that produces the "recently added" block is stored in config table as `name=views.view.content_recent`.

The view's config itself is in the data (blob) column of that config-row.

Views that get installed by contrib modules at install time are located in the config/install/views.view.* file of the module's folder.

Try

```
mysql> select * from config where name='views.view.content_recent';
```

Comment: Also don't forget to clear cache afterward.

Comment: "Active views" is a bit misleading here as disabled views are stored in the same place. Maybe "Installed views" would be a bit clearer?

Comment: @Rainer Feike Thanks for the answer. Spot on. I have found the views but I don't seem to find the corrupted view in that table. Do you have any input on that?

Comment: Did you check the "library" view, looks corrupt from your screenshot. Maybe try to delete it manually from the config table.

Comment: Think your corrupt view will not appear anywhere in the usual displays - cause it has no id. Try to delete the rows from "config" table one by one untill the WSOD disappears. Don't forget to clear the cache after each delete.